# How to display Admob Ads on my Mobile app build in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, admob, ads, phonegap-build

I want to display AdMob ads on my mobile app. I have built my app using HTMl5, CSS3 and Javascript with PhoneGap build using the cordova plugin. Can someone link me to steps on how to display ads on my mobile app ? Is there a better Ads solution than Admob that i can try ?

PLease Note i cannot make any changes to Java files since i using PhoneGap Build to build my app.

Answer (score 5):

AdMob plugin was not available in PhoneGap Build before, as the old policy did not allow binary files submitted.

But now, they made a great change to their policy (http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/09/phonegap-build-new-features/), and now allow you to use the plugins in Cordova plugin registry.

To use Admob plugin in your app, just configure it in your config.xml:

`<gap:plugin name="com.google.cordova.admob" version="2.5.0" source="plugins.cordova.io" />`

The instruction and example code are documented at its github project homepage:

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

to display a banner Ad:

```
if(AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
    adId:admobid.banner, 
    position:AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER, 
    autoShow:true} );
```

to display a full screen Ad:

```
// preppare and load ad resource in background, e.g. at begining of game level
if(AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {adId:admobid.interstitial, autoShow:false} );

// show the interstitial later, e.g. at end of game level
if(AdMob) AdMob.showInterstitial();
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no Phonegap Build solution for displaying Ad content. However, Phonegap is currently working on supporting Binary plugins which will open the door for an admob solution through the build service. This question posted on the Phonegap Build community site has a couple responses from employees if you would like to take a look:

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/phonegap_build_admob_advert_plugin?utm_source=notification&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=new_comment&utm_content=topic_link

If you switch to locally building your apps, there are solutions available. 
I have a detailed description of implementing an admob plugin for Cordova 3.3 here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22647417/admob-plugins-compatible-with-phonegap-3-4

The command line can be a pain to setup, but once it's in place it is easy to use and you have greater control over the app.

Answer (score 1):

From today it's possible as described in [this post](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/09/phonegap-build-new-features/). To do so, add the following tag in your `config.xml` file:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.admob.google" source="plugins.cordova.io" />
```

You can see the demo app [here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-phonegap-build-demo)